# Concept solving primitive of a function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

[image: The answer is B , but is there a way by solving the problem without going full arctan , knowing that we'll have to go from a function to the primitive and back to the function (F')]

The answer is B , but is there a way by solving the problem without going full arctan , knowing that we'll have to go from a function to the primitive and back to the function (F').

I might not be clear what I'm asking but let's try anyway.

I'm looking for a shortcut using the definition of integral and derivative.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the fundamental theorem of calculus with some chain rule, 
$$
F'(x)=\frac{1}{x^6+5}3x^2\implies F'(-1)=\frac{3}{6}=\frac 1 2
$$

In general, for nice functions $f$, 
$$
F(x)=\int_0^{u(x)}f(t)\mathrm dt\implies F'(x)=f(u(x))u'(x)
$$